# accessing an element like array in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have data in the form:
id,val1,val2

example

```
1,0.2,0.1
1,0.1,0.7
1,0.2,0.3
2,0.7,0.9
2,0.2,0.3
2,0.4,0.5
```

So first I want to sort each id by val1 in decreasing order..so somethng like

```
1,0.2,0.1
1,0.2,0.3
1,0.1,0.7
2,0.7,0.9
2,0.4,0.5
2,0.2,0.3
```

And then select the second element id,val2 combination for each id
So for example:

```
  1,0.3
  2,0.5
```

How do I approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pig is a scripting language and not relational one like SQL, it is well suited to work with groups with operators nested inside a FOREACH. Here is the solutions:

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, v1:float, v2:float);
B = GROUP A BY id; -- isolate all rows for the same id
C = FOREACH B { -- here comes the scripting bit
    elems = ORDER A BY v1 DESC; -- sort rows belonging to the id
    two = LIMIT elems 2; -- select top 2
    two_invers = ORDER two BY v1 ASC; -- sort in opposite order to bubble second value to the top
    second = LIMIT two_invers 1;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as id, FLATTEN(second.v2);
};
DUMP C;
```

In your example id 1 has two rows with v1 == 0.2 but different v2, thus the second value for the id 1 can be 0.1 or 0.3

Answer (score 1):

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, v1:int, v2:int);
B = ORDER A BY id ASC, v1 DESC;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE id, v2;
DUMP C;
```

Comment: should B = ORDER A BY v1 DESC; (for sorting in descending order)?

Comment: also..what I want is .. for each id .. order by v1 in descending order??? and then select the second element for each sorted id?? Can you please again take a look at the example again .. My bad if the question wasnt clear

Comment: Hi.. Will B order all the rows in A based on v1.. or just for each id.. I think its the former.. But.. I want to sort id wise.. rather than for the whole table.. I just started using script but I think I should be first grouping A by id and then order by v1...? But i am not able to find the write syntax?

Comment: I have updated B. That should work. However, selecting the 2nd biggest v2 is the difficult problem here. I'd probably write an aggregate UDF for that. Think of max, only that you do not return the max, but the "2nd biggest value". See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Aggregate+Functions

Comment: Would it be simpler..if we LIMIT the result by 2?? and then get the last value (i think the minimum??) I can think of this algorithmically but not as per pig syntax?? Can you help me penning this down ?

Comment: LIMIT does not work per group, but only on all tuples in the relation. That's why I think your proposed solution won't work if you want to know the 2nd highest value per id. I think writing a UDF is the way to go.

Comment: Fred - LIMIT works just fine on the group in Pig 0.10 at least. Just try the code from my answer.

Comment: yep, I did not know about that nested foreach. Thanks!