# How can I select record with minimum value in pig latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have timestamped samples and I'm processing them using Pig. I want to find, for each day, the minimum value of the sample *and the time of that minimum*. So I need to select the record that contains the sample with the minimum value.

In the following for simplicity I'll represent time in two fields, the first is the day and the second the "time" within the day.

```
1,1,4.5
1,2,3.4
1,5,5.6
```

To find the minimum the following works:

```
samples = LOAD 'testdata' USING PigStorage(',') AS (day:int, time:int, samp:float);
g = GROUP samples BY day;
dailyminima = FOREACH g GENERATE group as day, MIN(samples.samp) as samp;
```

But then I've lost the exact time at which the minimum happened. I hoped I could use nested expressions. I tried the following:

```
dailyminima = FOREACH g {
  minsample = MIN(samples.samp);
  mintuple = FILTER samples BY samp == minsample;
  GENERATE group as day, mintuple.time, mintuple.samp;
};
```

But with that I receive the error message:

```
2012-11-12 12:08:40,458 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: 
<line 5, column 29> Invalid field reference. Referenced field [samp] does not exist in schema: .
Details at logfile: /home/hadoop/pig_1352722092997.log
```

If I set minsample to a constant, it doesn't complain:

```
dailyminima = FOREACH g {
  minsample = 3.4F;
  mintuple = FILTER samples BY samp == minsample;
  GENERATE group as day, mintuple.time, mintuple.samp;
};
```

And indeed produces a sensible result:

```
(1,{(2)},{(3.4)})
```

While writing this I thought of using a separate JOIN:

```
dailyminima = FOREACH g GENERATE group as day, MIN(samples.samp) as minsamp;
dailyminima = JOIN samples BY (day, samp), dailyminima BY (day, minsamp);
```

That work, but results (in the real case) in a join over two large data sets instead of a search through a single day's values, which doesn't seem healthy.

In the real case I actually want to find max and min and associated times. I hoped that the nested expression approach would allow me to do both at once.

Suggestions of ways to approach this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use ORDER and LIMIT nested in FOREACH. See  similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253863/accessing-an-element-like-array-in-pig

Comment: Thanks alexeipab - that guided me to a working solution, and a good one in this case. I'll add as an answer shortly. I'd still like to understand why the combination of MIN and FILTER doesn't work, and why FILTER works without MIN but fails when the MIN is applied first.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to alexeipab for the link to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253863/accessing-an-element-like-array-in-pig).

One working solution (finding both min and max and the associated time) is:

```
dailyminima = FOREACH g {
  minsamples = ORDER samples BY samp;
  minsample = LIMIT minsamples 1;
  maxsamples = ORDER samples BY samp DESC;
  maxsample = LIMIT maxsamples 1;
  GENERATE group as day, FLATTEN(minsample), FLATTEN(maxsample);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, which has the advantage that it doesn't sort the entire relation, and only keeps the (potential) min in memory, is to use the PiggyBank [ExtremalTupleByNthField.](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/ExtremalTupleByNthField.html) This UDF implements Accumulator and Algebraic and is pretty efficient.

Your code would look something like this:

```
DEFINE TupleByNthField org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.ExtremalTupleByNthField('3', 'min');

samples = LOAD 'testdata' USING PigStorage(',') AS (day:int, time:int, samp:float);

g = GROUP samples BY day;   

bagged = FOREACH g GENERATE TupleByNthField(samples);

flattened = FOREACH bagged GENERATE FLATTEN($0);

min_result = FOREACH flattened GENERATE $1 .. ;
```

Keep in mind that the fact we are sorting based on the *samp* field is defined in the DEFINE statement by passing *3* as the first param.